# Dropwizard upgrade to 2.1.4 - requests and responses are not logged

Tags: java, jetty, dropwizard

I have upgraded most of the project libraries, mainly Java from 8 to 17, Spark from 1.6 to 3.3, and Dropwizard from 1.1.3 to 2.1.4 and related. However, after the upgrade, HTTP requests are not logged either on the console or in the file. Has anyone ever had this issue? Other application logs are logged as usual, on the console and in the file.

I followed the configuration guide, https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#request-log, and I don't see the settings have changed. I also tried a sample project created using the maven archetype, and the request/response are logged as expected.

Actual project logs (Set Jetty log level to DEBUG): You can see the usual request/response is not logged

```
INFO  [2023-07-18 18:22:29,594] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@38b88037{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2023-07-18 18:22:29,603] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started application@4f2e21d7{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9090}
INFO  [2023-07-18 18:22:29,604] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started admin@6666410a{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:9091}
INFO  [2023-07-18 18:22:29,604] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @18279ms
DEBUG [2023-07-18 18:22:36,396] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: REQUEST POST /api/v3.0/TestEndpoint on HttpChannelOverHttp@42a3fd0d{s=HttpChannelState@76b39ac5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=//localhost:9090/api/v3.0/TestEndpoint,age=2}
DEBUG [2023-07-18 18:22:38,000] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: handled=true async=false committed=true on HttpChannelOverHttp@42a3fd0d{s=HttpChannelState@76b39ac5{s=HANDLING rs=BLOCKING os=COMPLETED is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=1},r=1,c=false/true,a=HANDLING,uri=//localhost:9090/api/v3.0/TestEndpoint,age=1606}
```

Sample project logs: You can see the usual request/response code in the logs

```
INFO  [2023-07-18 03:28:59,534] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@60dd0587{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2023-07-18 03:28:59,546] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started application@3a2b2322{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO  [2023-07-18 03:28:59,547] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started admin@5e1218b4{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO  [2023-07-18 03:28:59,547] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @1593ms
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [18/Jul/2023:03:29:03 +0000] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 54
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [18/Jul/2023:18:25:13 +0000] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 190
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [18/Jul/2023:18:25:16 +0000] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 4
[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] - - [18/Jul/2023:18:25:16 +0000] "GET /info HTTP/1.1" 200 6 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" 3
```